# Rollover mouse to change picture

Tags: html

I have a five jpg's of eyes looking, left, right etc using HTML... I want the pictures to change so when the mouse pointer is at the left of the picture the eyes look left and so on. I thought using coordinates to find the position of the pointer, then some, if statements to change the picture, would work but I can't figure it out.

Here is what I have so far, am I on the right lines?

```
function myFunction(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    document.getElementById("showCoor").innerHTML = coor;
}
```

Comment: You are more or less on the right track, but it's not really clear what you look for. Do you want us to write the code for you or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: So why 5 specifically? If you had centre of screen and compass points I could visualise 5 images. Would you only want to look up, if cursor was in NE section of page? More explanation needed for the 5/what you want/ require.

Comment: I don't need to use any of the code I have tried to write... I could do with the problem-solving. I want it to look like a picture of eyes that follow the mouse around the screen. I have a picture for the center, left, right, up and down, but I can't work out the code for a web page. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="img0.png" id="img" onmousemove="myFunction()">
<p id="showCoor"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    document.getElementById("showCoor").innerHTML = coor;
    // Divide image in parts and handle each part
    if(x < width/2){
        img.src = "img1.png";
    }
    else{
        img.src = "img2.png";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sagar, I have tried this but I can't get it working, I think the code I've written before isn't correct. Might need to start again. I'm still very new to this and appreciate your help.